# Adding item to shopping cart using php and html

Tags: php, html, session, get

I am attempting to implement a shopping cart using php, and html. The problem I am having is storing the id of the product to be stored using a session. The following is the code that I have at the moment:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
//There are three HTML Forms that take and display input, and output.

<?php
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();

if(isset($_GET['search'])){
  echo "<table border=1>";
  echo "<th>Product Image</th>";
  echo "<th>Product Name</th>";
  echo "<th>Price</th>";

  foreach($xml->categories->category->items->product as $product){
    $imageURL = $product->images->image[0]->sourceURL;
    $id = $product['id'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href= 'buy.php?buy=".$id."'><img src=".$imageURL."></img></a></td>";
    echo "<td>".$product->name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".'$'.$product->minPrice."</td>";
  }
}

if(isset($_GET['buy'])){
  $product_id = $_GET['buy'];
  if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$product_id);
  }
}

print_r ($_SESSION);
?>
```

What the first if statement does is that it gets the search word, and gets the closest results. It then displays an image, name, and price. When you click on the image, there is a href and it is supposed to be added to the shopping cart. That is where the second if statement comes into play. If the image has been clicked I want to get the id and store it in session. It stores the id of the product when clicked upon, but when I go back to add another item the previous id is replaced with the new id. Could anybody explain to me where I went wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the session cart before assigning to empty array. Check my code below. Is it the solution working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();

check like this:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['cart']))
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
```

That should solve it

Answer (score 1):

First you have to assign an array to your **$_SESSION['cart']**. Otherwise it will store only a single value.

```
$ids = array();

$_SESSION['cart'] = $ids;
```

Then it will work.

Comment: I tried doing this, but the first value is still being replaced by the  values after it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use array to store multiple values:

```
$shop_array= array(); // this is create the array with the name shop_array
// now create the session and assign the shop_array to creating session
$_session['mycart'] = $shop_array;
```

You can check the stored values using `print_r()` function:

```
print_r($_session['mycart']);
```

You will get the result set of stored ID's.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I was already aware of it. That is the reason for me knowing that the array elements are being replaced. This was the same suggestion by someone else, and does not seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this,

```
          if(isset($_GET['buy'])){
                $product_id = $_GET['buy'];       
                  if(!in_array($product_id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
                      $_SESSION['cart'][]=$product_id;
                  }             
             }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, it still replaces the old value with the new value instead of accumulating them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to options to store cart - sessions and cookies i personally prefer sessions try this code for storing cart in sessions

```
if(isset($_POST['item_src']))
{
  $_SESSION['name'][]=$_POST['item_name'];
  $_SESSION['price'][]=$_POST['item_price'];
  $_SESSION['src'][]=$_POST['item_src'];
  echo count($_SESSION['name']);
  exit();
}
```

complete tutorial for creating add to cart system here http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/simple-add-to-cart-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php.php